# Change or overwrite response badrequest message web api c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, webapi2

How are you, people I need to change the response message of the return of BadRequest().

When I use the request like this,  `BadResquest("error: you can not pass these values")`

I want to my api return something like this:

```
{"error: you can not pass these values"}
```

but the endpoint retuned this :

```
{"Message":"error: you can not pass these values"}
```

I don't want the word "Message" in my response, is there any form to overwrite or change the response?.

Answer (score 0):

You're free to create what ever response message you like.  see http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results

The BadRequest() helper method is just that.  It's a workload reduction method that takes care of boilerplate stuff.